# Как с основной страницы загрузить данные из других фреймов?

Tags: jquery, framework

Всем привет! У меня на одной странице загружается несколько фреймов. Как с основной страницы загрузить данные из других фреймов? Например:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Тег FRAME</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>     
  <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
              alert($("#mainFrame").content().find("#textID").length);
          });
  </script>     
 </head>
 <frameset rows="50,50" cols="*">
   <frame src="scheta.html" name="topFrame" scrolling="no" noresize>
   <iframe src="/index-blank.html" width="300" height="100"></iframe>
   <frameset cols="50,50">
     <frame src="table_col.html" name="leftFrame" scrolling="no" noresize>
     <frame src="scheta.html" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame">
   </frameset>
 </frameset>
</html>
```

---

### scheta.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  
        <input type="text" value="qwerty" id="textID" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу вариант только через GET-параметр.